# Stuck on a ClassCastException with Hibernate but only occasionally on tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate

I don't suppose anyone can help here, but if you have any pointers it would be much appreciated. Basically since moving Tomcat (7) to Java 7 we sometimes get the below exception. The only thing that seems to sort it is restarting the tomcat. I cannot reproduce it locally on my machine, so I know all the mappings etc are good. I was wondering if anyone has any ideas?

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of hub.app.model.DocumentFolder.id
 at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:171)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:183)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3596)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3312)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:181)
 at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.noCascade(CascadingAction.java:348)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:139)
 <snip>
 Caused by: 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@18b0170
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor754.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:145)
 at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:183)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3596)
 at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3312)
 at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:181)
 at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.noCascade(CascadingAction.java:348)
 at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:139)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:131)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:122)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:65)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:35)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:969)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1136)
 at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:94)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:49)
 at hub.app.model.dao.EntityAccessCountHibernateDAO.addAccessCount(EntityAccessCountHibernateDAO.java:33)
 at hub.app.model.dao.EntityAccessCountHibernateDAO$$EnhancerByGuice$$3ea802fe.CGLIB$addAccessCount$0(<generated>)
 at hub.app.model.dao.EntityAccessCountHibernateDAO$$EnhancerByGuice$$3ea802fe$$FastClassByGuice$$64e6ae4b.invoke(<generated>)
 at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
 at com.google.inject.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:64)
 at com.wideplay.warp.persist.jpa.JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.invoke(JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.java:68)
 at com.google.inject.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:64)
 at com.google.inject.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:44)
 at hub.app.model.dao.EntityAccessCountHibernateDAO$$EnhancerByGuice$$3ea802fe.addAccessCount(<generated>)
 at hub.app.service.hotstuff.HotStuffService.recordAccess(HotStuffService.java:40)
```

Edit:
I've just had this again on another tomcat instance. This time the exception was slightly different:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of hub.app.model.DocumentFolder.id
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3596)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3312)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$9.noCascade(CascadingAction.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:54)
    ... 19 more
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:145)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Most likely some of the `DocumentFolder.id` is null?

Comment: Hi Rosdi - no I don't think so - it either consistently fails every time, or (for the same entity) once tomcat is restarted works consistently until next server restart

Comment: You should show us what is in `EntityAccessCountHibernateDAO.java line 33` That is where it started.

Comment: ClassCastExceptions often happen if one class is loaded from different classloaders. Things can get extremely complicated if there are two different versions of same library in classpath. So I'd turn on -verbose:class and analyze whether there are any jars I don't expect.